# Include Avatar in SearchBar Material3

Tags: java, android, searchview, searchbar

I want to make a search bar in the topbar with an avatar taken from a Google account, as shown in the picture. The picture is taken from the material.io site, but there are no methods for creating such a search on the site. I searched the internet for a long time and didn't find how to do it. The search brings back the old search iterations in the top bar.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhnIG.png)